# Is it mandatory to be in same wifi network to communicate using NearBy Api?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-beacon-platform, google-nearby

I'm using google's NearBy API to enable communication between android devices using BLE. I was followed [these](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-started#step_1_get_google_play_services) steps. Also used [these](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby) samples.

Those samples are working well but the problem here is WiFi(staying in same network) connection is mandatory. But My intention is communication should be possible only using BLE(bluetooth). Let me know if any libraries which simplifies the  BLE and Beacons usage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide some description why you down voted . Let me know What I missed.

Comment: I think this is a valid question, and don't deserved a -1. I myself was initially I was not sure about this topic as well. I upvote your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out https://developers.google.com/nearby/, there are at least 2 types of nearby now.

1. The Nearby Connection feature will required Local Network.
2. The Nearby Messages can work across network, as long as both are connected to the internet. Check https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=92&v=hultDpBS22s and https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview